# tor-arm not displaying connection information

Tags: nyx

When running tor-arm, I am unable to see information about connections.  Even when running arm as root, the Connections tab remains blank as well as the connections graph showing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include the line

```
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0
```

in your torrc file in order to force Tor to allow arm access to the list of currently open sockets it has which it then uses to create the list of connections.

Answer (score 0):

If connections used to show and now they don't, try just leaving nyx open to the connections screen for a good minute. I'm not sure if the connections list being too long or the relay server being CPU overloaded is the problem (or both). But sometimes I just have to wait.

(Also I tried `DisableDebuggerAttachment 0`, and I got a message about this not being allowed and my tor relay just shut down immediately when I did a systemctl reload.)